# Git push fails on peculiar email mangling bug

Tags: git, github

Suddenly I am seeing this when I try to push to git

```
Username for 'https://github.com': mtobis@gmail.com
Password for 'https://mtobis@gmail.com@github.com':
```

Then it rejects me. Until today the email was not mangled.

```
git config user.email
```

returns

```
mtobis@gmail.com
```

as expected. I have no idea why it is appending @github.com to my email or how to convince it to stop.

What is going on? How do I push now???

I have done nothing to my git configuration as far as I can recall!

Comment: Your username is not the same as your email.

Answer (score 1):

Your username is "mtobis", not "mtobis@gmail.com".